# How do I use polygon centroids within a GeoQuerySet?

Tags: geodjango

I have two models: neighbourhoods and boroughs, each containing a polygon field.

I am trying to construct a QuerySet that will give me the neighbourhoods within a given borough. I expected to use *within* or *contained*:

`neighbourhoods_in_borough = Neighbourhood.objects.filter(poly__within=Borough.poly)`

However, it is not always the case that a neighbourhood lies cleanly within a borough. Neighbourhood polygons roughly align with a Borough, but may weave in and out slightly. As such, filters like within or intersects either leave out neighbourhoods or include too many surrounding a Borough which happen to slightly overlap.

Because I only want the Neighbourhoods which are predominantly inside of a given Borough, I thought I would test to find Neighbourhoods whose centroids are within a given Borough:

`neighbourhoods_in_borough = Neighbourhood.objects.filter(centroid__within=Borough.poly)`

However, you can spot the issue here: centroid is not a field on the model, and so the above does not work. I did think adding a preceding query (e.g. Neighbourhood.objects.centroid() ) would make the centroid available to be used in some form, but it fails for the same reason as the example above.

Is it possible to filter based on a polygon's centroid rather than the polygon's shape?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy enough to get a `centroid` field to use in queries. First, modify your `Neighborhood` and `Borough` models so that they have this field, e.g.:

```
class Neighbourhood(models.Model):
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    poly = models.PolygonField()
    centroid = models.PointField()

class Borough(models.Model):
    objects = models.GeoManager()
    poly = models.PolygonField()
    centroid = models.PointField()
```

Next, alter the tables in your database so that they have these fields; here are what the queries looks like in PostGIS (one at a time), *assuming your SRID is EPSG:4326*:

```
ALTER TABLE myapp_neighbourhood ADD COLUMN centroid geometry(POINT,4326) NULL;
ALTER TABLE myapp_borough ADD COLUMN centroid geometry(POINT,4326) NULL;
```

Now, in the Django shell or by executing in a script, you can loop over the Neighbourhood records updating their `centroid` field with the calculated centroid. The `model_att` argument exposes the calculated `centroid` [as an argument on model instances](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#geoqueryset-methods):

```
for each in Neighbourhood.objects.centroid(model_att='c'):
    each.centroid = each.c
    each.save()
```

Now a `centroid` field will be available in your spatial queries.

**However,** are you sure that an intersection is not the right geometry relationship for your application? From your narrative, it sounds like it should be. I don't know if you're using PostGIS on the back-end, but [according to the PostGIS reference](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Intersects.html):

> If a geometry or geography shares any portion of space then they
>   intersect. For geography -- tolerance is 0.00001 meters (so any points
>   that are close are considered to intersect)

This sounds like the right assumption for your application.

Comment: Your instructions for adding the `centroid` field to my models worked perfectly. I modified the Neighbourhood model, altered the database in the dbshell, and then updated the model in the shell. 

I am now getting the results that I expected. It has occurred to me that I might be safer with point_on_surface, but I expect I can repeat this process using point_on_surface instead of centroid if that's the case.

I am using PostGIS, but intersects gives more results than I want because I get hoods surrounding the Borough (they intersect just slightly).

Thank you so much for the detailed answer.

Comment: You might try checking for `ST_Intersects(...) AND NOT ST_Touches(...)` to remove these edge cases that are giving you trouble.

Answer (score 5):

[@Arthur](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/69176/68277) answer, addresses a pre Django-1.9 approach.

> Using [GeoQuerySet methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#geoqueryset-methods) is now deprecated in favor of the new
> [Geographic Database Functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/functions/).

Using Django-1.9 I have achieved the same result as follows:

models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels


class Municipality(geomodels.Model):
    municipality_area = geomodels.MultiPolygonField()
    centroid = geomodels.PointField(default='POINT(37.943 23.715)')
```

`$manage.py shell`

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Centroid
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> from my.models import Municipality
>>> Municipality.objects.update(centroid=Centroid(F('municipality_area')))
```

You may also override the `save` method to automatically calculate the value of the centroid attribute:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels


class Municipality(geomodels.Model):
    municipality_area = geomodels.MultiPolygonField()
    centroid = geomodels.PointField(default='POINT(37.943 23.715)')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.centroid = self.municipality_area.centroid
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```